# How to access a related table data in a foreach loop in Razor file in MVC4 project?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to access the "ApplicationStatusId" using the following,

```
var applicationStatus = applicationItem.ApplicationDetermination.ApplicationStatusId;
```

But I can access the "ApplicationStatusId" in the same razor file using following,

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => applicationItem.ApplicationDetermination.ApplicationStatusId)
```

[image]

[image]

Please see the error below,

[image]

Comment: You need to find out which variable is null.  Either debug it, or break up the statements into separate lines to find out which reference is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by putting a null check for the "ApplicationDetermination" object. It was trying to get the ApplicationStatusId from a null object.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
 var applicationStatus = @applicationItem.ApplicationDetermination.ApplicationStatusId;
```